# When I load a new image in a TBitmap I must destroy the existing one first?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, delphi-2009

I am loading multiple images from resources in a `TImageList` at runtime with this code:

```
 Bitmap:=TBitmap.Create;
 MyIcons:=TImageList.Create(self);
 Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,'DEFAULT16');
 MyIcons.AddMasked(BitMap,clRed);
 Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,'FOLDER16');
 MyIcons.AddMasked(BitMap,clRed);
 Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,'BACK16');
 MyIcons.AddMasked(BitMap,clRed);
 Bitmap.Free;
```

I want to know if I should destroy the previous bitmap (`Bitmap.Assign(nil)`) when I load a new one or this is done automatically in `LoadFromResourceName` method. I mean I don't want to have memory leakage...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. When `LoadFromResourceName` executes, it clears any memory and resources used by the previous image, and loads the new one.

Your code is fine, modulo the missing `try/finally`. It should be:

```
Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
try
  ....
finally
  Bitmap.Free;
end;
```

Without that, should an exception be raised in between assigning to `Bitmap`, and destroying the object, the object would not be destroyed and would be leaked.